# Fixing toggle all behavior in checkbox element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle all checkboxes on a table and my code works but has a few issues and I don't find how to get ride of them. So here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggleCheckbox').on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $("#codigoArancelarioBody").find("input:checkbox").click();
    });
});
```

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/nnfg80x1/) Fiddle I setup for testing and do this tests:

- Mark the first checkbox (the one at table heading level) the rest of them inside `#codigoArancelarioBody` get checked and this is right
- Mark first the checkbox at the first row (the only at table body level) and then mark the toggleAll you will see how things goes wrong since if I check the toggleAll them all should remain checked and that's the wrong part on my code

How I can fix this? Also I'll like to add a class 'removedAlert' to those TR I mark, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two click event handlers, one for the check/uncheck all box and one for the other ones

**JS**

```
$('#toggleCheckbox').on('click', function () {
    var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#codigoArancelarioBody").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle);
});

$("#codigoArancelarioBody input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#toggleCheckbox').prop("checked", false);
    } else if ($("#codigoArancelarioBody input:checkbox").length == $("#codigoArancelarioBody input:checkbox:checked").length) {
        $('#toggleCheckbox').prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6ypzm6nv/)

---

> since the same code will be applied in a lot of places on my code and
>   to avoid DRY, I'll like to pass the selector as a parameter in all
>   your code solution could you edit your post to achieve this?

```
$toggleCheckBox = $('#toggleCheckbox');
$checkBoxTbody = $("#codigoArancelarioBody");

$toggleCheckBox.on('click', function () {
    var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
    $checkBoxTbody.find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle);
});

$checkBoxTbody.find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $toggleCheckBox.prop("checked", false);
    } else if ($checkBoxTbody.find("input:checkbox").length == $checkBoxTbody.find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
        $toggleCheckBox.prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/cvz6rnjs/)

Comment: since the same code will be applied in a lot of places on my code and to avoid DRY, I'll like to pass the selector as a parameter in all your code solution could you edit your post to achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to add an extra functionality which is toggle button enabled if at least one checkbox is checked and it's not working, can you take a look to the fork I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/ot96p9mL/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the "click" event for something else you can do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggleCheckbox').on('change', function () {
        var toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $("#codigoArancelarioBody").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', toggle ).closest('tr').addClass('removedAlert');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually executing what you told it to do, i.e. every time I ***click*** the checkbox on top ***click*** to other checkboxes. This way if a box is checked it will uncheck itself, because it won't mind if the top is checked or not.

What you really want is "when I ***check*** the box on top, ***check*** all the others, when I ***uncheck*** it, then ***uncheck*** all the others", which is sort of different as you see.

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
     // best practice: always store the selectors you access multiple times
     var checkboxes = $("#codigoArancelarioBody").find("input:checkbox"),
         toggleAll = $('#toggleCheckbox');

      toggleAll.on('click', function () {
         // is the top checkbox checked? return true, is it unchecked? Then return false.
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        // .prop('checked', true) makes it checked, .prop('checked', false) makes it unchecked
        checkboxes.prop('checked', $toggle);
    });
 });
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/nnfg80x1/3/